# VNC over USB tether?

Tags: usb-tethering, vnc

Edit:  I want to connect to a vnc server on  a PC from an Android client via usb tethering.

I'm trying to use my phone as a way of interacting with a headless linux box.  I can't get VNC or connectbot to work with usb tethering - they just time out.  Work as expected when I connect the phone through wifi.  Is there something I need to do to make this work? Open some ports or something?  I could get primitive ftp working through a USB tether.

Anyway I'm in need of suggestions of where to start looking - or if it is at all possible.

Wifi and bluetooth don't suit my use-case

Cheers

Comment: Opening ports in the tethering network is always a problem on Android. If you already have USB connection why don't you just use `adb`. Using adb you can forward ports in both directions. But you could even skip that by simply using [scrcpy](https://github.com/Genymobile/scrcpy) which works like VNC (IMHO even better) but simply requires and adb connection.

Comment: Thanks for the info . To clarify I want to control my linux desktop with my phone. Will scrcpy work in that direction? A cursory read of the README leads me to believe it's geared in the other direction.

Comment: No scrcpy is only for remote controlling Android. You should edit your question and make it clear that the VNC server is running on the PC side.